# Python for loop xrange increment

Tags: python, loops

My for loop is;

```
for r in xrange(0,444):
    if(r == 5):
     r=r+4
```

but r is not increment for in loop. What is that problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement?

Answer (score 3):

In python, this type of for loop is not synonymous with the C-style:

```
for(int r = 0; r < 444; ++r)
    if (r==5)
        r += 4;
```

Instead, Python sees this as a collection of objects. In a for loop, Python will see:

```
for r in range(5):
```

as (essentially)

```
for r in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
```

Anytime you change `r`, it does not affect the list itself. It only affects the locally scoped object `r`, which will be overwritten during the next iteration. If you want to do that, you can do:

```
r = 0
while r < 444:
    if r == 5:
        r += 4
    r += 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure, he ask what is wrong with his code but instead that you propose another way to do that

Comment: and the forth solution is wrong
when r = 5 you step over number 6

Comment: Fixed. It should be skipping 6 - 9

Answer (score 0):

Because r variable every time is recalculated by xrange object.

Answer (score 0):

An xrange is defined by xrange(start, stop[, step]).  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange.

Your code by not defining step is using step=1, so your xrange is essentially a list of integers 0 through 443. When you write:

```
for r in xrange(0,444):
```

you are only giving a variable name, "r", to associate with each item in the range during that items "turn" in the iteration.  The code block you give:

```
for r in xrange(0,444):
    if(r == 5):
        r=r+4
```

is asking to iterate through this list and when it reaches 5 increase r by 4, but the xrange object is already built and the for statement will continue to look at each integer in the object.

For example:

```
>>> for r in xrange(0, 10):
...     if (r == 5):
...         r = r + 4
...     print r
... 
0
1
2
3
4
9  # 5 is changed to 9 but the iteration continues with the next 'r' in the xrange
6
7
8
9
>>>
```